# Slow loading of the categories page and the paginator of the products on the same page in question

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

this is a screen recording related to the issue: https://calip.io/U7eBbuDW#q1GpTStt.

Explanation of the problem:
Going to https://mcgroup.store/it/2-home, the page loading is very slow (it takes several seconds to load).
The CPU of the server where the site is hosted shoots at 100% and the memory also goes to high percentages when I load that page.
And the same thing also happens in the product paginator when I click on 1,2,3, etc. or on the arrow to move forward.

Before I do this page or paginator load, the server's CPU and memory levels are always at normal levels.

I've already tried clearing the cache and turning on automatic clearing, but nothing.
Same thing by activating the "special" caches.
Also all php settings requirements meet Prestashop's recommended requirements.

Contacting Prestashop support I was told that there is a problem in the "ybc_themeconfig" module that adds an Ajax tool to the product list.

How can I fix this problem?

**I use Prestashop 1.7.8.5**

Comment: Disable the module told by PrestaShop support and then check again if the issue has been fixed or not.

Comment: Tried, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

To check if your slow loading is due to hosting performance or your Prestashop itself, try to switch back to the default Prestashop theme.

If i'm not mistaken your theme is 'Pro Business - Multipurpose Prestashop Theme '
Your theme has not adapted to Prestashop 1.7.8.5 contact the theme builder, if the issue is indeed your theme.

Comment: The problem persists also with the default Prestashop theme

Comment: Video recording: https://calip.io/ucNsIoMZ#11aMeMds

Comment: The same problem with the paginator of the products.
This is the video-recording: https://calip.io/F3OgXYq0#n8AABeNk